# Help using SOAP for login

Tags: php, soap

I'm designing a website for an organization that's a state chapter of a national organization. The national organization has implemented a member login that I need to use for the state website.

My website is in PHP, and it looks like the server for the national organization is using SOAP and ColdFusion. I'm a total newbie to using SOAP, so I'm probably missing a bunch of things.

The national organization sent me this information:

> Fields to collect on a form
>   mausername
>   mapassword
>
> Static variables
>   componenttype Value: Chapter
>   components Value: NM
>   authusername Value: NMChap
>   authpassword Value: USA
>   authpagealias Value: Login
>
> The webservice is located here:
>   https://www.apta.org/AM/APTAAPPS/ComponentAuthWebService/aptamemberauthorize.cfc?WSDL
>
> The following fields will be returned:
>   Email, FirstName, LastName, LoggedIn, Phone_Release, UserName
>
> If LoggedIn returns “true,” the member has been authenticated as a member of the component.
>
> This has been implemented and tested here: http://aptadevisg.apta.org/am/aptaapps/test/NM_Chap_test_form.cfm

Based on this information and reading the SOAP documentation, this is what I came up with:

```
$apta_server = 'https://www.apta.org/AM/APTAAPPS/ComponentAuthWebService/aptamemberauthorize.cfc?WSDL';

$post_data['mausername'] = '107150';
$post_data['mapassword'] = 'barnes';
$post_data['componenttype'] = 'Chapter';
$post_data['components'] = 'NM';
$post_data['authusername'] = 'NMChap';
$post_data['authpassword'] = 'USA';
$post_data['authpagealias'] = 'Login';

$options = array('trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 0);
$options['location'] = 'https://www.apta.org/AM/APTAAPPS/ComponentAuthWebService/MemberAuth';

try
{
    $client = new soapclient($apta_server, $options);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{

}

$client->debug_flag = 1;

try
{
    $result = $client->__soapCall('MemberAuth', array($post_data));

    echo '<h1>Soap Result</h1><pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
}
catch (SoapFault $fault)
{
    echo '<h1>Soap Fault</h1><pre>';
    print_r($fault);
    echo '</pre>';
}

echo '<pre>getFunctions<br>';
print_r($client->__getFunctions());
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>getTypes<br>';
print_r($client->__getTypes());
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>getLastResponseHeaders<br>';
print_r($client->__getLastResponseHeaders());
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>getLastResponse<br>';
print_r($client->__getLastResponse());
echo '</pre>';
```

When I print out the result of the __soapCall(), I get a message of: "looks like we got no XML document."

I really don't know what I'm doing regarding SOAP, so any help would be greatly appreciated. You can view the results of the test login attempt at: http://rc19.info/test_login.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have the $options['location'] wrong. Try the location of the actual web service:

```
$options['location'] = 'https://www.apta.org/AM/APTAAPPS/ComponentAuthWebService/aptamemberauthorize.cfc';
```

Second, though not necessary, you don't have to call $client->__call("MemberAuth"). You can do $client->MemberAuth() and pass the parameters in like so:

```
$result = $client->MemberAuth($post_data['mausername'],$post_data['mapassword'],$post_data['componenttype'],$post_data['components'],$post_data['authusername'],$post_data['authpassword'],$post_data['authpagealias']);
```

Comment: I'm curious how you came to the right port address, as the one in the WSDL indicates an unconnectable `https://www.apta.org/` instead of `https://www.apta.org/`. Was it just a guess or further insight?

Comment: Thank you, Bob. I think it's working. Actually, I had to do both of your suggestions. Any idea why I needed to change the $client->__soapCall() to $client->Memberauth(). Reading the SOAP documentation, I thought that __soapCall() was the preferred way. 

I have the new code at http://rc19.info/test_login2.php

Comment: Wrikken, for a while it seemed like the web services server wasn't working. I was getting inconsistent results when making calls. The only difference between mine and his location was he included the method name at the end.

Mitchell, technically both should work just fine. The difference is probably the order of the parameters. The $client->Memberauth() lets you put the parameters in the right order.

Comment: See comment by Wrikken regarding why my $client->__soapCall() was not working--I had redeclared an existing array as an array.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a superfluous `array` in there (you could see that with `$client->__lastRequest()`, so change:

```
$result = $client->__soapCall('MemberAuth', array($post_data));
```

To:

```
$result = $client->__soapCall('MemberAuth', $post_data);
```

After that, I get either an 'could not connect to host' (if I follow the port of the WSDL, https://aptaweb.apta.org/AM/APTAAPPS/ComponentAuthWebService/aptamemberauthorize.cfc), or a redirect (302) to the website with a bunch of cookies set if I choose yours (https://www.apta.org/AM/APTAAPPS/ComponentAuthWebService/MemberAuth). Use a `stream_context` with `$context = stream_context_create(array('http'=>array('max_redirects'=>1)));` and `$client->__getLastRequestHeaders();` to see the redirect in action.

Curiously enough, Bob's solution of https://www.apta.org/AM/APTAAPPS/ComponentAuthWebService/aptamemberauthorize.cfc works, but is in no way indicated by the wsdl itself as far as I can tell.

Comment: Wrikken, you're right about the extra array. I changed that as you suggested to $result = $client->__soapCall('MemberAuth', $post_data); along with Bob's change to the $options['location'] and it works. Thanks for pointing that out, and I'm glad to see that the __soapCall() syntax works.